# How is express able to catch thrown Errors without next() in asynchronous code?

Tags: node.js, express

I was going through [HabitRPG/habatica's](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica) repository trying to learn best practices for node js projects. I came across a piece of code where custom errorHandler was able to catch errors even in asynchronous code (without using next()). Does anyone know how one can achieve this ?
[image]

NotAuthorized is a class extending Error class.

Comment: I assume that's being done by whatever _receives_ this object, could do e.g. `app[route.method](route.url, ...route.middlewares, (req, res, next) => route.handler(req, res).catch((err) => next(err))`. Seems to mostly happen [here](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/blob/60f251a8c7c2bfb9fa39e144d900bec9786fbd2f/website/server/libs/routes.js#L15-L58), but SO isn't here to explain random off-site repos.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thankyou so much. With some more digging around, found this line `const _wrapAsyncFn = fn => (...args) => fn(...args).catch(args[2]);`.

Comment: Yes sorry for asking a random repo question here. I was looking around for error handling in express but couldn't find a neat and tidy way to handle asynchrounous errors. My initial plan was to pass next to all route handlers and call it from there but now I know the right way. Thanks !

Comment: Note this is also covered in the Express docs: http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#use-promises

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh! Thanks once again.